# Could a polygonal path on $n \times n$ lattice cross itself?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I am working on a problem from Problem solving strategies (Larson) and I encountered the following problem:

Let $S$ denote an $n$-by-$n$ lattice square, $n \ge 3$. Show that it is possible
to draw a polygonal path consisting of $2n - 2$ segments which will pass
through all of the $n^2$ lattice points of $S$.

This problem isn't supposed to be a simple induction problem. The goal, as I conclude from the chapter it pertains to, is to use induction along with generalization of the problem. In other words, I am supposed to prove a more general version of the problem (which I have to figure out) and solve it by induction. However, just poking around with some examples, I quickly arrived at a solution using induction if the paths are supposed to cross. I want to ask your opinion if polygonal paths are supposed to cross. I want to solve the problem and I don't want to cheat myself accidentally.

Comment: What is your definition of *polygon*?

Comment: No definition was provided, I assume it means straight lines (no curves).

Comment: If you mean a continuous path with orthogonal lines through every point that meets its start without crossing it path, it is not possible with a $3 \times 3$ lattice. Is $n$ an *even* number?

Comment: It doesn't have to meet its starting point

Comment: Then why do you call it *polygonal* which means a closed system?

Comment: I am assuming that it means using only straight lines

Comment: In that case, you simply take a "spiral" route. Why is a proof of that needed?

Comment: You're supposed to use $2n-2$ segments. That means for $3 \times 3$ Lattice, you're supposed to use $4$ segments

Comment: Hmm I see, but I can't complete the $3 \times 3$ lattice with $4$ lines, it needs $5$. Perhaps the lines do not need to be *contained* by the lattice.

Comment: 4 lines are sufficient for $3 \times 3$ lattice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108148/discussion-between-crystal-math-and-weather-vane).

Comment: Where is the "cross or not cross" condition expressed?

Comment: In graph theory, paths don't cross. That's why I am asking if they can cross here, since I expect this problem to be hard.

Comment: Wikipedia: [polygonal chain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) (also called polygonal path) @WeatherVane

Comment: Wait, are they supposed to cross? I can't find anything

Comment: @crystal_math I don't see the relevance of graph theory here. In graph theory, "path" has a meaning relating to a graph's nodes and edges. It isn't geometrical. The problem here is geometrical.

Comment: In the specific context of this problem, the polygonal path is allowed to cross itself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for 3x3 grid

[image]

It may show the induction for larger grids.

Comment: That's the solution I came up with for $3 \times 3$ but the path crosses itself on the top–left corner

Comment: @crystal_math I supposed that. Just wanted to put a picture.